# Mail::queue Closure serialization error Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, serialization, closures, iron.io

I promise this is not just another Mail::queue newbie question. I had Laravel 4.2 app working with Iron.io Push queues
Then, I upgraded to Laravel 5.1 and my Mails just stopped working. I have UserController from which I send user account verification email to the registrant.

```
//Used for Mail
$data=['msg'=>$msg];
$details=array(
  'email'=>$email,
  'name'=>$name,
  'subject'=>$subject,
  'msg'=>$msg);
\Mail::queue(['text'=>'emails.contactus'],$data,
  function($message) use ($email,$name,$subject) {
    $message->from($email,$name);
    $message->to(Config::get('app.site_support'))->subject($subject);
});
```

Iron.io is configured properly with keys and such. My Mail queuing app and queue processing apps are different.

Error I get is

```
[2015-10-19 18:12:32] production.INFO: Queue POST Item received  
[2015-10-19 18:12:32] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Class 'UserController' not found' in /var/www/app/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/SerializableClosure.php:130
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Class 'UserCont...', '/var/www/app...', 130, Array)
#1 /var/www/app/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/SerializableClosure.php(130): Closure->bindTo(NULL, 'UserController')
#2 [internal function]: SuperClosure\SerializableClosure->unserialize('a:5:{s:4:"code"...')
#3 /var/www/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(300): unserialize('C:32:"SuperClos...')
#4 /var/www/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(286): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->getQueuedCallable(Array)
```

Looks like Mail::queue is serializing UserControl which is not available in queue/receive processor app. I tried placing UserController in processor app but still get the same error

Comment: Where is the usage of `UserController` on the above code to understand what the error exactly means, can you elaborate the above code to understand better?

Comment: UserController sits in queuing and receiving apps in App\Http\Controllers with namespace commented out. RouteServiceProvider has protected namespace='';

Answer (score 0):

So this is just for another poor soul who's facing the same issue. 
After a lot of searching I resorted to a separate Job class that sends email and takes $data (for view template data) and $details (specifying email template, 'to' email address and subject) in its constructor

Then I Mail::send in handle method.

I fire this job using Controllers $this->dispatch method just as they said in Laravel Documentation

Answer (score 0):

After updating Laravel from 4.2 to 5.1 you need to update the IronMQ version to "4.*" in composer.json. Laravel 5.1 is only compatible with IronMQ v4.